# grep return the string in between words

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, grep, amazon-rds

I am trying to use grep to filter out the RDS snapshot identifier from the rds describe-db-snapshots command output below:

```
"arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:123456789:snapshot:rds:apple-pie-2018-05-06-17-12",
"rds:apple-pie-2018-05-06-17-12",
```

how to return the exact output as in

```
rds:apple-pie-2018-05-06-17-12
```

tried using

```
grep -Eo ",rds:"
```

but not able to

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk 'match($0,/^"rds[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'   Input_file
```

Comment: this will still capture both lines in the output:

Comment: @user2155404, ok check now and let me know if All is Well?

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13, this time it doesn't return anything

Comment: @user2155404, for your shown Input_file it worked perfectly fine for me, could you please check if you have carriage characters in it? BY doing `cat -v Input_file` once and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

Your `grep -Eo ",rds:"` is failing for different reasons:

- You did not add a `"` in the string to match
  Between the comma and rds you need to match the character.
- You are trying to match the comma that can be on the previous line
  Your sample input is 2 lines (with a newline in between), perhaps the real input is without the newline.
- You want to match until the next double quote.

You can support both input-styles (with/without newline) with

```
grep -Eo '(,|^)"rds:[^"]*' rdsfile |cut -d'"' -f2
```

You can do this in one command with

```
sed -rn 's/.*(,|^)"(rds:[^"]*).*/\2/p' rdsfile
```

EDIT: Manipulting stdout and not the file is with similar commands:

```
yourcommand | grep -Eo '(,|^)"rds:[^"]*' |cut -d'"' -f2
# or
yourcommand | sed -rn 's/.*(,|^)"(rds:[^"]*).*/\2/p'
```

You can also test the original commands with `yourcommand > rdsfile`.
You might notice that rdsfile is missing data that you have seen on the screen, in that case add `2>&1`

```
yourcommand 2>&1 | grep -Eo '(,|^)"rds:[^"]*' |cut -d'"' -f2
# or
yourcommand 2>&1 | sed -rn 's/.*(,|^)"(rds:[^"]*).*/\2/p'
```

Comment: what about reading from the console output, instead of from a file?